# Functional Equation by Substitution?

Tags: functional-equations, substitution

I've been trying to solve this:

$f: \Bbb{R\setminus \{1\} \to \Bbb{R}}, f(2-x) + x f(\frac{1}{1-x}) = 3-x $

I suppose I can simplify slightly by replacing $x$ with $(2-x)$ to give:

$f(x) + (2-x)f(\frac{1}{x-1}) = x+1$

I'm assuming I need to use substitution(s) from here, but I'm embarrassingly rusty at maths these days, and I was hoping someone would be able to give me a hint or two about how best to proceed (not looking for a full solution).

Thank you.

Comment: Hint. Substituting $x$ to $1-x$, $f(1+x)+(1-x)f(\frac{1}{x})=2+x$, which makes the F.E. simpler. Then, not sure, but you can make $f(a)+f(b)=\lambda_{1}, f(b)+f(c)=\lambda_{2}, \cdots,, f(x)+f(a)=\lambda_{k}$ and maybe you can have $f(a)$.

Comment: Thank you. With the second part (ie the lambdas) - I don't think I understand what you're suggesting. Could you possibly explain in a bit more detail please?

Comment: Standard trick for such functional equations is to substitute $\frac{1}{x-1}$ into the equation, then it will contain $f(\frac{1}{x-1})$ and $f(\frac{x-1}{x})$. Then if you substitute $\frac{x-1}{x}$ the equation will have $f(\frac{x-1}{x})$ and $f(x)$. So you have three equations from which you can express $f(x)$,$f(\frac{1}{x-1})$ and $f(\frac{x-1}{x})$ (although you only really need the first one). See similar example [Solving a functional equation using Mobius transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159900)